# Salesforce Pardot

Tags: pardot

just heading up my first Pardot implementation. We plan to generate leads through Pardot landingpages in the feature as well as we want to contact existing leads. Is there anything special that needs to be considered when connecting Salesforce with Pardot and creating the intial sync between SF and Pardot?

Comment: isn't that covered in the [documentation](http://help.pardot.com/customer/portal/articles/2128445-setting-up-the-salesforce-connector) ?

Answer (score 3):

The main thing  to bear in mind is that you'll need to do an initial import of leads and contact from salesforce into Pardot. After which any new lead or contact created in Salesforce will automatically get created in Pardot, as long as you have the setting enabled in the connector.

Answer (score -1):

Many considerations, which  vary by how you will use Pardot.  E.g. not all the automations work the same way; some are retroactive! Do you want your older leads in Pardot (great for reengagement), or not? Plan ahead for syncing: who should win: Salesforce or Pardot's values ? Before you connect, specify this, field by field. Connect your campaigns.

Working with a consultant can lead to superior results. Particular if they're experts at Salesforce, Pardot and marketing.

Comment: You're answering a 5 year old question.